# how to get json response from sqlite query with marshmallow python flask

Tags: python, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, marshmallow

I have searched a lot but didn't get solution to this. I have queries with SQLite and return to the HTML pages. But now I am going to use Reactjs, need to send the response to Reactjs pages.
Here is my database.py file:

```
class User(db.Model, Mixin):
    __tablename__ = "users"
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.Integer, unique=True)
    timestamp = db.Column(db.DateTime(), index=True, default=datetime.utcnow)
    prefix = db.Column(db.String(2))

    def __init__(self, name, prefix):
        self.name = name
        self.prefix = prefix

class UserSchema(ma.Schema):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('name', 'prefix')
        load_instance = True


user_schema = UserSchema()
user_schema = UserSchema(many=True)
```

Here is my queries which need to be send response as json

```
import app.database as data
@core.route('/user_display/<int:user_id>', methods=["GET"])
def user_display(user_id):
    all_users = data.User.query.all()
    dump_data = data.user_schema.dump(all_users)
    return jsonify(dump_data)
```

The above code send josn response like 
 "data": [
        {
            "name": "user1",
            "prefix": "Mr"
        }
    ],
but I need the result from the below query.

**user_name = data.User.query.filter_by(id=user_id).first().name**

**user_id = data.User.query.order_by(data.User.id.desc()).first().id**

but getting the below error

```
 obj_prototype = next(iter(obj))
TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

How to resolve this issue and get the user name and ids?

Comment: Setting `UserSchema(many=True)` makes `marshmallow` to expect an iterable, e.g., a list of `User`s. If you are trying to return serialized data for a single item, you do NOT want to set `many=True`. Also, I'd suggest passing that option when you use `load(s)` and `dump(s)` method instead of when you initialize the schema.